# How to add date picker into MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

In phpMyAdmin I have a datetime picker for date related fields. In Workbench I don't see that in form editor mode. For enum I see a select box which is nice, but for date time I don't see anything.

How to turn it on? Or is there and addon that can enable this feature in MySQL Workbench.

It's one thing that get's on my nerves, because I need to manually fix some things from time to time in some databases and the date and time picker would help a lot.

Comment: Anybody? If that's not possible at all, that's ok, I will go back to phpmyadmin of adminer. I just thought that if it's call *bench it will offer many useful features out of the box. Datepicker, surely, is not something extraordinary to ask for, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree. It should have a datetime picker.